# Files uploaded to ftp server, corrupted why?

Tags: c#, server, ftp, upload

Files are uploading successfully but with corrupted files.
Kindly check my code and fix my problem.
I think my problem in this line:

```
 byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());;
```

```
string ftpurl = "ftp://IP";
            string ftpusername = "u09z0fyuu"; // e.g. username
            string ftppassword = "Yamankatita1@"; // e.g. password

            string PureFileName = new FileInfo(file_name).Name;
            String uploadUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", ftpurl, "PDPix", file_name);
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.  
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.  
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(_mediaFile.Path);
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());;
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            _ = DisplayAlert("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription,"OK");
```

Comment: Are you uploading UTF8-encoded _text file_? If not, that seems likely to be your problem.

Comment: No, I need to upload only image files. Kindly help me thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said you're trying to upload *image files*. You can't treat these as UTF8 because they are *binary data* and they are not encoded with UTF8. You need to **treat binary data as binary data**.

You can read the *bytes* directly:

```cs
byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(_mediaFile.Path);
```

**Explanation**

UTF8 can't represent all possible values of a `byte` (0x00 - 0xFF) as characters and roundtrip them back to a binary format again. We can observe this with the following code:

```
byte[] input = new byte[8];
RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create().GetBytes(input);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", input.Select(i => i)));

string tmp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(input); // interpret arbitrary bianry data as text
// the data is corrupted by this point
byte[] result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tmp); // convert the text back to a binary form (utf8-encoded)
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result.Select(i => i)));
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/DAVW73525)

Here we generate 8 random bytes, print their values, try to interpret them as a `string`, convert that string back to bytes, and print their new values.

For the following 8 bytes:

```
16, 211, 7, 253, 207, 91, 24, 137
```

We got the following bytes as a result:

```
16, 239, 191, 189, 7, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 91, 24, 239, 191, 189
```

And just like that, our data is corrupted! Long story short: don't use text encoding for binary data.